# Transaction Unlock Time in Monero GUI?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

i would like to use the [unlock time feature](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/moneropedia/unlocktime.html) to send Monero and make sure the receiver cannot spend them before a certain date. is there a way to use that feature in Moneros GUI wallet?

Answer (score 1):

As @dEBRUYNE said, the the GUI doesn't support that. But you can use in the CLI

```
locked_transfer [address] [amount] [block lock time(limit of 4 years)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The unlock time feature is currently not implemented in the GUI. One would thus have to use the CLI to utilize the feature.

Comment: this is a great feature with a lot of potential for many use cases, that i wasn't aware of since yesterday. would love to see this getting implemented in a future version of Monero GUI. thank you for the info.